# how can I restore default fonts in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: display, fonts

I have accidentally deleted some of the fonts from /usr/share/fonts folder. They must have been crucial since now I have various display problems ( underscore and font size display ).

I have already tried resetting gnome and system fonts settings but it does not solve the problem. It seems that I need the missing fonts files but I don't remember the names.

Do you know where I can find a list of preinstalled fonts of Ubuntu 11.10, so that I can locate and restore the missing files ?

Answer (score 1):

did you re-install them?

I found a few fonts, that seems to be standard (see 1-4 below, or [here](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Schriftarten))
You can get them by:

```
sudo apt-get install <your fonts>
```

1. ttf-ubuntu-font-family
2. fonts-ubuntu-font-family-console
3. ttf-dejavu
4. fonts-linuxlibertine

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was away. Installing the fonts does not seem to fix the problem. What is more I formated my drive, installed ubuntu 12.04 and problem persists. I found another topic with a similar issue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/183284/why-is-the-font-spacing-on-some-websites-broken/196446#196446