# How to fix overlapping text on some pages while using Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

Similar to this question: [Why is the font spacing on some websites broken?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183284/why-is-the-font-spacing-on-some-websites-broken)

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 with Google Chrome and I'm experiencing an issue where some webpages have overlapping text. The text will overlap horizontally, not vertically, and can sometimes be fixed by moving the mouse over the text. I tried to fix it the same way the other question was fixed, but I don't have a `/home/.fonts/` directory.

Comment: I'm seeing text overlapping too, intermittently on web pages where there are transitions between e.g. bold + normal fonts. Ubuntu 13.10 64bit, chrome 32.0.1700.107.  No problems like this with 13.04 (w/ older version of chrome too)

Comment: Surprisingly, I haven't had it happen in the past 2 months. I don't know if this is because of an update, or just because of luck.